# Phoenix vs Rails - full stack benchmark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phoenix-framework

I'm looking for full stack benchmarks comparisons between Phoenix and Rails.

I found this post (but it doesn't hit the database) http://www.littlelines.com/blog/2014/07/08/elixir-vs-ruby-showdown-phoenix-vs-rails/

A Blog index page would be fine (with variable posts list) - as long as it hits the database.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/

Comment: Not sure that this question fits SO. Maybe you should try on other websites or mailing lists/slack channels?